# In next-auth using TypeORMAdapter how can I extend the UserEntity with relations?

Tags: next.js, typeorm, next-auth

How can I extend the `UserEntity` with a `oneToMany` relation to new Entity?

e.g.

```js
 @Entity({ name: "users" })
  export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id!: string
  
     ...


    @OneToMany(() => DatabaseEntity, (database) => database.userId)
    databases!: DatabaseEntity[]
  }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser Entity metadata for UserEntity#databases was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options. {
  message: "Entity metadata for UserEntity#databases was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.",
  stack: "TypeORMError: Entity metadata for UserEntity#databases was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.\n" +
```